# animate is not a function error appear

Tags: jquery

I have a image slider and I have managed images like this

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| +-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +----------+ |
| |     | |      | |      | |      | |      | |          | | visible images
| +-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +----------+ |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
  +-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +----------+  
  |     | |      | |      | |      | |      | |          | overflow hidden images
  +-----+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +------+ +----------+
```

and would like to animate / fadeIn to hidden images on mouseover() function like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/bts7e/)

But when I used firebug it's saying .animate() is not a function. Anyway I noticed in my fiddle when I mouseover all red spans then only it is animated amazingly.

**Question**

How can I animate to the span on which mouse is hovered `without placing a class inside spans and selecting like using nth-child`?

---

I need to set margin-top only on one span on which mouse is hovered. Also I have to use fadeIn effect.

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/clink/bts7e/17/) //working with float: left

Comment: Only way animate is not a function is if you're calling it before the method becomes available. Are you using inside a doc ready statement? 
$(function(){}); type thing?

Comment: yes inside ready function

Comment: it's not clear what you want, you want the hovered element to go up and reveal the element that's "below" it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted to do?

```
$('div').mouseover(function(){
   //alert('hi');  //working
    $('span').animate({'margin-top':'-10px'},1000); 
});
```

Edit - scratch that, here's what you need to change:

```
span{
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: this animates all spans. I need one span on which hovered.

Comment: Yeah that I used see in my question

Answer (score 1):

It's because the inline-block, use `block` and `float: left`, then it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/bts7e/3/

Comment: yeah it's in fiddle but I've explained in my question there is images in my localhost its not working even float left.

Comment: Could you provide your html code? We need to know its structure.

Comment: in the slider the images are set display inline.

Answer (score 1):

To get each span to rise to the top on `mouseover`, you need to make sure they are block level elements (or inline-block), with `vertical-align` set to `top`. This will make sure the margin is actually having an effect.

[See this fiddle for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsNb2/)

The problem with your example is that margin will not trigger a mouseover event. Other properties such ass padding *will* trigger it, because that is considered part of the element. Since your particular example can't use padding (otherwise it would be changing the size of the red spans, **you could use some other property that is invisible to the user, but gives you the functionality you require**. I recommend a white border.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UZKwY/1/

Comment: overflow hidden is set instead not apply vertical-align top!

Comment: How do you expect your spans to be hovered if they're hidden?

Comment: Notice in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xydx/) that when you hover over the margin of an element, it will not trigger a mouseover event.

Comment: Yeah nice one. but how to set overflow hidden for border part

Comment: Note in the fiddle that the `div` is given a height of `20px`. For `overflow: hidden` to work, you must specify a height.

Comment: I'm confused to use overflow hidden to top borders only could you show me a demo

Comment: Your answer deserve for +1 with me.

Comment: [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UZKwY/1/) shows that you can animate the size of the `border-top`. It changes the border size from `10px` to `0px` over a period of time.